# bootstrap:I want to push the div down when I change the window to xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[code:]

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```

[here is my code,and review in a middle window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLPav.png)

[when I change the window to xs,And I want to achieve that：](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bffkt.jpg)

Please help me,tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put that div last and then use push and pulls to re-arrange the columns when on the same line.

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/cayabimaqo/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-4">4</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-4">4</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-4">4</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 col-xs-12">12</div>
</div>
```

P.S. This could also be done with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)